# Pandas add column with values from two df on partly matching column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an easy question most likely but still am stuck on how to solve what I want.
I have a two dataframes which match one column "giftID" and want to create a new column in df1 adding the values from df2 matching the giftID. I tried it with np.where and all different kinds but can't get it working.

```
df = pd.read_csv('../data/gifts.csv')
trip1 =df[:20].copy()
trip1['TripId']=0
subtours = [list(trip1['GiftId'])] * len(trip1)
trip1['Subtour'] = subtours

trip2 = df[20:41].copy()
#trip2['Subtour'] = [s]*len(trip2)
trip2['TripId']=1
trip2['Subtour'] = subtours = [list(trip2['GiftId'])] * len(trip2)
mini_tour = trip1.append(trip2)
grouped = mini_tour.groupby('TripId')
SA = Simulated_Anealing()
wrw = 0
for name, trip in grouped:
    tourId = trip['TripId'].unique()[0]
    optimized_trip,wrw_c = SA.simulated_annealing(trip)
    wrw += wrw_c
    subtours = [optimized_trip]*len(trip)
    mask = mini_tour['TripId'] ==  tourId
    mini_tour.loc[mask,'Subtour'] = 0
```

Input:

```
df  giftID  weight  
1    A      4      
2    B      5      
3    C      6  
4    D      7   
5    E      12  

df1  giftID  subtour
1    A       1, 3, 4
2    B       1, 3, 4
3    C       1, 3, 4

df2  giftID  subtour
1    D       2, 5, 8
2    E       2, 5, 8
```

Output:

```
df  giftID  weight  subtour
1    A      4       1, 3, 4
2    B      5       1, 3, 4
3    C      6       1, 3, 4
4    D      7       2, 5, 8
5    E      12      2, 5, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can `pd.concat`,  `df1` and `df2`

```
import pandas pd
df12 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0) # axis = 0 means row wise
```

Then `merge` the `df12` with your main one:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df,df12,how='left',left_on='giftID',right_on='gift')
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I tried the merge aswell but thing is, that df1 has different size than df2. Basically I create multiple different dataframes that contain partial data (same giftID) as the main dataframe and want to fill all the values in that column in the main dataframe from the multiple dataframes

Comment: Okay sorry I don't fully understand what you need. I think if you can edit your question, give sample data of the different data frames, and show a sample of your desired output, it will help us get you the solution you need.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm not specific enough. I'll update my post.

Comment: Tried to put a sample of my input and output,

Comment: Thanks I think that did it for me. appreciate your help @sophods